# JS JSON - почему работает именно так?

Tags: javascript, json, логика

Здравствуйте. Есть такой код JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {     
  $.getJSON('https://...?callback=?', function(data) {
      //ответ от сервера успешно получаю
      alert("Im in JSON");        

  });
  alert("Im out JSON");

});
```

Вопрос: почему в результате сначала выполняется алерт "Im out JSON", а только потом "Im in JSON" ? Почему такая логика как бы "наоборот" ?

Comment: **асинхронность**

Comment: Молниеносный ответ, спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

`$.getJSON` асинхронное событие, то есть выполняется после получения ответа от сервера и не блокирует выполнение остального кода.

Answer (score -1):

Это из-за асинхронности. Чтобы отключить ее, можно добавить это:

```
jQuery.ajaxSetup({async:false});
```

**UPD:** Но лучше не надо.

Comment: [Но лучше не надо](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27736186/2076787).